# Django - excluding objects from queryset results in "expression tree is too large"

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I'm working on a project that handles astronomical data (literally and figuratively) and have hit a roadblock when trying to exclude observations that require complex filtering.

To be more specific, each `Observation` has one or more `SpectralWindow`s. Users must be able to query observations by - among others - looking to their frequency coverage in relation to a band, a frequency range or an emission line. Regardless of the selected option, this coverage can be redshifted inside a specific z interval.

Since it's a bit hard to directly translate this to `__lte`-like selectors, I just filter the queryset and manually exclude observations that don't cover the calculated frequency range. Something like this:

```
for o in obs_result:
                covers = covers_ranges(z_bands, o) # <--- a more complex filtering solution
                if(not covers):
                    obs_result = obs_result.exclude(id=o.id) # <--- here's the problem!
                # update the min and max frequency values across the obs set
                else:
                    min_max = get_min_max_f(o)
                    min_freq = min(min_freq, min_max[0])
                    max_freq = max(max_freq, min_max[1])
```

The resulting query ends up like this:

```
SELECT ... FROM "common_observation" WHERE ("common_observation"."dec" >= 1.3365999999999998 AND "common_observation"."dec" <= 3.3366 AND "common_observation"."field_of_view" <= 300.0 AND "common_observation"."ra" >= 149.2375 AND "common_observation"."ra" <= 151.2375 AND NOT ("common_observation"."id" = 415) AND NOT ("common_observation"."id" = 416) AND NOT ("common_observation"."id" = 611) AND NOT ("common_observation"."id" = 612) AND NOT ("common_observation"."id" = 753) AND NOT ("common_observation"."id" = 758) AND NOT ("common_observation"."id" = 883) AND NOT ("common_observation"."id" = 884) AND NOT ("common_observation"."id" = 968) AND NOT ("common_observation"."id" = 984) AND NOT ("common_observation"."id" = 985) AND NOT ("common_observation"."id" = 995) AND NOT ("common_observation"."id" = 996) AND NOT ("common_observation"."id" = 997) AND NOT ("common_observation"."id" = 998) AND NOT ("common_observation"."id" = 999) AND NOT ("common_observation"."id" = 1000) AND NOT ("common_observation"."id" = 1001) AND NOT ("common_observation"."id" = 1002) AND NOT ("common_observation"."id" = 1052) AND NOT ("common_observation"."id" = 1053) AND NOT ("common_observation"."id" = 1086) AND NOT ("common_observation"."id" = 1087) AND NOT ("common_observation"."id" = 1088) AND NOT ("common_observation"."id" = 1089) AND NOT ("common_observation"."id" = 1090) AND NOT ("common_observation"."id" = 1091) AND NOT ("common_observation"."id" = 1092) AND NOT ("common_observation"."id" = 1093) AND NOT ("common_observation"."id" = 1099) AND NOT ("common_observation"."id" = 1100) AND NOT ("common_observation"."id" = 1111) AND NOT ("common_observation"."id" = 1154) AND NOT ("common_observation"."id" = 1156) AND NOT ("common_observation"."id" = 1157) AND NOT ("common_observation"."id" = 1158) AND NOT ("common_observation"."id" = 1159) AND NOT ("common_observation"."id" = 1204) AND NOT ("common_observation"."id" = 1205) AND NOT ...
```

...followed by a couple more hundreds of similar lines. When the list gets iterated over, this behemoth understandably throws an "expression tree is too large" error.

I already tried to just evaluate the queryset to a list and filter from there, but it won't include related objects, meaning I can't look into related objects/fields (`Observation.SpectralWindow.start`, for instance).

What's the protocol for these problems, if there are any?

Comment: would it be possible to do this database level wise creating a view and imporing it as model in django with mange set to false?

Answer (score 0):

You may try to store ids in a list and then exclude all ids which are in the list, like this:

```
exclude_ids = []
for o in obs_result:
                covers = covers_ranges(z_bands, o) # <--- a more complex filtering solution
                if(not covers):
                    #obs_result = obs_result.exclude(id=o.id) # <--- here's the problem!
                    exclude_ids.append(o.id)
                # update the min and max frequency values across the obs set
                else:
                    min_max = get_min_max_f(o)
                    min_freq = min(min_freq, min_max[0])
                    max_freq = max(max_freq, min_max[1])
obs_result = obs_result.exclude(id__in = exclude_ids)
```

Comment: Wouldn't that solution cause the same error later on? I'd still be applying a ton of `AND NOT ("common_observation"."id" = xyz)` filters to the query.

Comment: UPDATE: now I got a "too many SQL variables error".

Comment: Can you share `Observation` and `SpectralWindow` models? And also what does z_bands contain? How do you calculate  `covers = covers_ranges(z_bands, o)`

Comment: Sure, [here's](https://pastebin.com/SFDVt7nW) the pastebin of the models and the error - raw data show the ids that have to be excluded. Writing those down to a list did avoid chained `AND NOT ("common_observation"."id" = 968)` expressions, but I'm still dealing with too long of a query.

Comment: Forgot to mention: `z_bands` contains user-defined spectral windows that have a certain redshift value applied to them. `covers_ranges` simply iterates through an observation's spectral windows and returns true if any of them overlaps with those in `z_bands` - meaning this observation will be included in the plot.

Comment: I'm afraid you'll have to somehow translate `covers_ranges` logic into ORM query. If it is as simple as comparing `SpectralWindow`'s start and end with with `z_bands`' start and end then you may use `Subquery` (or `Exists` clause) to exclude results from those returned values which will not travel from and to database. If you share `covers_ranges` code I can try to help you with this. I do not completely understand what spectral window means :)